# How to display multiple parameter value in excel report in TestNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, test-report

I have created test script for the upload file.
In the script, I have written the code for upload different kind of file and check the result.

But i have confusion about passing multiple data to the excel.

I'm using below code:

```
@DataProvider(name = "Authentication2")
public static Object[][] credential2()
{
    List<String> invaliddatalist=Arrays.asList(filepathinvalid,filepathinvalid2);
    int len=invaliddatalist.size();
    Object[][] objArray = new Object[len][];
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            objArray[i] = new Object[1];
            objArray[i][0] = invaliddatalist.get(i);

        }
    return objArray;            
}

public void Wrongdata(String[] appdata) throws InterruptedException 
{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        // List<String> invaliddataList = Arrays.asList(filepathinvalid,filepathinvalid2); 
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement choosefile=m1.getDriver().findElement(By.name("files"));

        for(int i=0;i<appdata.length;i++)
        {
             choosefile.sendKeys(appdata[i]);
        }

        WebElement upload=m1.getDriver().findElement(By.id("register-button"));
        upload.submit();
        WebElement dialog=m1.getDriver().findElement(By.id("dialog-notifications-error"));
        String errforinvaliddata=dialog.getText();
        System.out.println("err for invalid data->"+errforinvaliddata);
        String msg="Only pdf files are allowed.";

        if(msg.equals(errforinvaliddata))
        {
            for(int i=0;i<appdata.length;i++)
            {
                uploadinfo.put("i", new Object[] { i,appdata[i],"Fail" });
            }

            Assert.assertTrue(false);
            m1.getDriver().navigate().back();

        }
        else
        {
            String url=m1.getDriver().getCurrentUrl();

            System.out.println("errorurl->"+url);
            String exppath="https://veridocglobal.com/errorpage.htm?aspxerrorpath=/Document/Create";

            if(url.equals(exppath))
            {
                //uploadinfo.put("3", new Object[] { "3",p1,"error" });
                Assert.assertTrue(false);
                m1.getDriver().navigate().back();

            }       
        }       

    }

@AfterClass
public void afterclassmethod() throws IOException
{

    Set < String > keyid = uploadinfo.keySet();
    int rowid = 0;

    for (String key : keyid) 
    {
             HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowid++);
             Object [] objectArr = uploadinfo.get(key);
             int cellid = 0;

             for (Object obj : objectArr) 
             {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellid++);
                cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
             }
     }
     FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("path"));
     workbook1.write(out);
     out.close();
     System.out.println("xlsx written successfully");
}
```

Comment: What are the data you are going to pass excel?

Comment: which i have pass in array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@DataProvider(name = "Authentication2")
      public static Object[][] credentials2() {

            return new Object[][] { {"3","/home/rutvi/Pictures/download.jpg"},{"4","/home/rutvi/Downloads/Standards.docx"},{"5","/home/rutvi/Music/Shree_Hanuman_Chalisa-Hariharan[www.Mp3MaD.Com].mp3"}};

      }
    @Test(dataProvider = "Authentication2",priority=2)

    public void Wrongdata(String id,String p1) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //   List<String> invaliddataList = Arrays.asList(filepathinvalid,filepathinvalid2);

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        WebElement choosefile=m1.getDriver().findElement(By.name("files"));

        choosefile.sendKeys(p1);


        /*for(int i=0;i<appdata.length;i++)
        {
         choosefile.sendKeys(appdata[i]);
        }
        */
             WebElement upload=m1.getDriver().findElement(By.id("register-button"));
             upload.submit();

                WebElement dialog=m1.getDriver().findElement(By.id("dialog-notifications-error"));
                String errforinvaliddata=dialog.getText();


                System.out.println("err for invalid data->"+errforinvaliddata);

                String msg="Only pdf files are allowed.";


                if(msg.equals(errforinvaliddata))
                {

                    /*for(int i=0;i<appdata.length;i++)
                    {
                        uploadinfo.put("i", new Object[] { i,appdata[i],"Fail" });
                    }
                    */
                    uploadinfo.put(id, new Object[] {id,p1,"faill" });
                    Assert.assertFalse(true);




                    m1.getDriver().navigate().back();

                }
                else
                {
                    String url=m1.getDriver().getCurrentUrl();

                    System.out.println("errorurl->"+url);
                    String exppath="https://veridocglobal.com/errorpage.htm?aspxerrorpath=/Document/Create";

                    if(url.equals(exppath))
                    {

                        Assert.assertTrue(false);
                        uploadinfo.put(id, new Object[] { id,p1,"error" });
                        m1.getDriver().navigate().back();

                    }       
                }       

    }
```